# How to replicate client's issue with just a video?

Tags: manual-testing

One of our client faced an issue in the Mobile gaming app, and sent us just a video showing the bug. We do not know the Steps, prerequisites or environment of the App he is using and asked developers to fix it ASAP.

The issue is that the Username in 'Wallet' page is showing different than the actual username of the user. Developer assigned me the task to replicate this issue, and I tried every possible way to reproduce it, but all in vain. I even clarified the chunk of code in that module with Developer and it seemed fine for them.

Now, is there any other way to replicate it, or maybe I missed something and you may inform.

Comment: Are you able to go back to the client to request more information to help you replicate the problem?

Comment: @Moorpheus We would. But the issue client posted was not reproducing by his side, but from other users, who has raised issue. So the client directly forwarded the user's issue to us.

Comment: Can you find the logs of the exact call that returned the wrong data? Tools like Kibana probably make it straightforward to filter out your logs by using the client IDs and the timing that the issue happened.

Comment: What does that video has

Comment: @JoãoFarias Actually the issue reported was from other user's sides, which was received by Client. And client simply forwarded those issues to us.

Comment: @PDHide The video has the issue which other users are facing.. in user's Steps.. So we won't be able to know he prerequisites of the scenario

Comment: Jaypreet and that steps on video is not able to recreate the issue ? Then there is no point in wasting time . Go back to client or customer and ask for system log

Comment: I'm not sure why the down vote, this is a legitimate question about a common situation. The fact that the poster cannot effectively solve it doesn't require a down vote

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you understand you cannot solve the problem.

For future reference, and as a way to make something out of a bad situation, you can come up with a solution. Those can range from very simple list of questions your support should ask, to more sophisticated like having information dump from the software or good telemetry that you can match with the customer.

Answer (score 0):

All software testing solutions companies face these types of issues for the defects raised by clients. The best way is to take a call with client and verify the steps performed in the video that are causing the issue.

Apart from this, we can ask client about the details of platform used and system logs for the developer to replicate the issue.

Comment: I would like to ask the client to help me replicating the issue, but these issues which client posted are not reproduced by him, but by other USERS, who report the problems. So even the client won't know the steps.